# Apache2 mod-fcgi separate users for two applications

Tags: php, apache-2.4, fcgi

I try to configure my apache like this: https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-apache2-with-mod_fcgid-and-php5-on-ubuntu-8.10

The point is that I want to have an user for typo3 and one for livezilla.

I got this configuration working, with `top` I can see processes of apache under the user typo3 and livezilla running.

But if I try to get with one of those users out of their web directory with this PHP code:

```
<?php
$dirHandle = dir("../../../");
while (($f = $dirHandle->read()) != false) {
    echo $f."<br />";
}
```

I can view the files and even see whats in those files.
How can I prevent apache from allowing this?